# Floating point problem in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, floating-point

The code below is used to calculate the miles between two cities. In this case, it's for the distance from Yarmouth, ME to Yarmouth, ME - obviously zero - meaning that results for cities within X miles of Yarmouth should include Yarmouth itself.

The problem is that the latitude and longitude for Yarmouth seem to be causing some kind of floating point problem (I haven't seen this with other cities):

```
DECLARE @fromlong FLOAT, @fromlat FLOAT, @tolong FLOAT, @tolat FLOAT, @test FLOAT

SET @fromlong = 43.8219
SET @fromlat = -70.1758
SET @tolong = 43.8219
SET @tolat = -70.1758
SET @test = SIN(@fromlong / ( 180 / PI() )) * SIN(@tolong / ( 180 / PI() )) + COS(@fromlong / ( 180 / PI() )) * COS(@tolong / ( 180 / PI() )) * COS(@fromlat / ( 180 / PI() ) - @tolat / ( 180 / PI() ))

PRINT @test /*** Displays "1" ***/

SELECT 3963.0 * ACOS(@test) /*** Displays "a domain error has occurred" ***/
```

First, is this a SQL Server bug?

Second, what can I do to get around it? I know in the example above I could have some logic for `IF @test > 1`, but this example is distilled from a query embedded in a web app (not my choice), so I need to fix the query, i.e. fix the calculation, without resorting to TSQL if possible, and without distorting any other return values. Any ideas?

Comment: Why float if you need exact values?

Comment: Was I supposed to get an error executing the code?  I did not get one Just a result of 0.

Comment: Good catch - I went back and looked at the database and realized I was using SSMS 2008 but the database is 2005. I'll change the post accordingly.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "exact values"? The query itself doesn't have any variables declared - these are the types returned when you pull those parts of the query out individually.

Comment: I don't get an error on my machine either (neither SQL2005 or SQL2008). I do get that error if i do `SELECT ACOS(1.00000000000000000000001)` manually though. So what *can* you change anyway to fix this? Can you change it to `ACOS(CASE WHEN @test > 1 THEN 1 ELSE @test END)`? Can you implement your own ACOS function?

Comment: Well float datatypes should never be used if you are doing calulations, they are estimates not exact values. THat could cause your problem, but if it isn;t it still needs to be fixed as you can have huge rounding issues with float.

Comment: For more on floating point "issues". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

I worked with a financial app written entirely using floats.  It was a nightmare.

Comment: @HLGEM: he's using trig functions, so he's got floating point numbers whether he likes it or not. FWIW, I suspect Martin Smith has the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consensus from the comments seems to be the use of FLOAT. I only used FLOAT in the example because that was the datatype of the columns from which the latitude/longitude was being read, but that seems to be the heart of the problem. Since I can't change the datatypes of the columns themselves, the simplest solution was to change the datatype of the resulting calculation, which seems to work fine in all cases:

```
SELECT 3963.0 * ACOS(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 6), @test))
```

I realize leaving the calculation as a float could result in small rounding errors, but they are acceptably small for this application. Thanks all who commented.